# Where does one set Chrome's Trusted sites on a Windows 7 machine?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I'm a little confused by Chrome's settings and how they interact with Windows' settings.  In Chrome Settings, when I go to the "change proxy settings", I get the same settings dialog that comes up for IE settings.  So the confusing part is that I get that this pops up because I suppose the proxy is machine-wide, but this is also the same dialog that comes up under Windows Control Panel's Internet Options.

So the question really is--do all of the settings and tabs on this dialog affect Chrome as well as IE (or any other browser on the machine for that matter)?  It's just confusing that the IE settings come up when one is in Chrome settings.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to allow trusted uris (i.e. domains where NTLM SSO credentials will be passed by the browser to the site) there are specific settings in the browser to do this.

---

### For Chrome:

You have to add the command line switch:

```
--auth-server-whitelist="*example.com,*foobar.com,*baz"
```

As specified here:
http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/http-authentication

There are steps on how to add the switch here: 
http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/command-line-flags

---

### For FireFox,

it's under about:config (type that in as website in your browser). You have to click "I'll be careful, I promise!" and then modify 'network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris' in order to add the domain as the value separated by a comma. i.e.

```
example.com,foobar.com
```

---

Answer (score 1):

For the question "do all of the settings and tabs on this dialog affect Chrome as well as IE (or any other browser on the machine for that matter)", Chrome uses the system-wide proxy server settings. So whatever proxy server setting is configured for Internet Explorer on a a Microsoft Windows system will also apply to Chrome. If you initiate the proxy server change process from within Chrome, you will be changing the system-wide setting. Firefox allows you to "Use system proxy settings" (the default selection) or to 
select "[Manual proxy configuration](http://support.moonpoint.com/network/web/browser/firefox/finding-proxy-setting.php)" and specify settings different from the system-wide proxy server setting, so whether it is affected also depends on whether it is configured to use the system-wide proxy server settings or you chose "manual proxy configuration" or "no proxy" for its setting. But that's just for proxy server settings; not all Chrome settings will change system-wide settings for other browsers.